# doesn't TapGestureRecognizer work in iOS and UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

TapGestureRecognizer does not work on iOS and UWP but works fine on Android.
What should I do to get it to work on iOS and UWP?

It does not throw any errors.

The frames are inside the content page and the content pages are inside the tabbed page.

Thanks if anyone can guide me.

This is my code:

```
<StackLayout>
  <Frame  Margin="10,5" BackgroundColor="White" 
   CornerRadius="10"   HeightRequest="120"  IsClippedToBounds="True"
     InputTransparent="True" HasShadow="True"               
       BorderColor="Silver"  Visual="Material" Padding="0"            
    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Center">
                  
 
    <StackLayout Padding="0" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">

        <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers >
            <TapGestureRecognizer  Tapped="gesture"/>
        </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>

        <StackLayout Padding="-10" >
            <Grid ColumnSpacing="10" >
                   <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="125"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <StackLayout Padding="0,1,-10,-7"  >
                    <Image Aspect="AspectFill"  Margin="-1"   
                     Source="mypic.jpg"/>
                </StackLayout>

     <StackLayout Grid.Column="1" Padding="20" 
                  VerticalOptions="Center"  >
        <Label FontSize="Large" FontAttributes="Bold,Italic" 
            Text="Mercury"  TextColor="MidnightBlue"/>
                    <Label FontSize="Medium" Text="mytext" 
                       TextColor="DarkSlateGray"/>
     </StackLayout>
            </Grid>
         </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
  </Frame>
 </StackLayout>
```

code behind

```
private async void gesture(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
        await   Navigation.PushAsync(new page1());
   }
```

Comment: Just an observation as I'm looking at this on a phone but XAML can be tough to read without decent formatting. I recommend you do a document format ( Ctrl + K, Ctrl + D in Visual Studio on Windows) to get the opening and closing tags to at least line up. You can also set the options so attributes are lined up vertically so it makes them easier to read too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the <strike>InputTransparent="True"</strike> from the Frame tag.

```
<Frame Margin="10,5" BackgroundColor="White" 
       CornerRadius="10" HeightRequest="120" IsClippedToBounds="True"
       HasShadow="True" BorderColor="Silver" Visual="Material" Padding="0"            
       HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Center">
```

This should now work